# Johansen test for cointegration in R

Tags: var, forecasting

I am building a VAR model. As far as I understood by reading different articles in Internet, I need first to check stationarity. By using the adf.test I found out that the data that I have is not stationary. So the next step would be to check a cointegration relationship. I did it using Johansen-Procedure Unit Root / Cointegration Test.

`jo_eigen <- ca.jo(Canada, type="trace",ecdet="trend",spec="transitory")`

The first hypothesis,r=0, tests for the presence of cointegration shows that there is cointegration. Would it be correct to use VAR model for forecast in this case?

Thank you! 
BR
Anna

Answer (score 0):

Since there is statistical evidence that there is a cointegration relationship you should use a VEC model in order to take advantage of the relation between the time series.